# How do I add row(s) of text below a visual in vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

How do I add row(s) of text below a visual in vega-lite. For example, add the following 2 rows of text BELOW a simple bar chart.

Figure 1: New Chart

Author: Joe Blogs | Source: DataCentral

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28}, {"a": "B", "b": 55}, {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91}, {"a": "E", "b": 81}, {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19}, {"a": "H", "b": 87}, {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `title` config by changing the orientation. Refer below code or [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91},
      {"a": "E", "b": 81},
      {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19},
      {"a": "H", "b": 87},
      {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "title": {
    "orient": "bottom",
    "text": ["Figure 1: New Chart", "Author: Joe Blogs | Source: DataCentral"]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Multi titles can be added in `concat` views, below is the code and [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIaZJ1h2DcyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiioBKKigxEiCDGpoANqgYSD6wUxoAEwAHAC+ColoIABCqWhiYrn56ADCJagALADMFSBJACK1AJwAjM1JAKK1mT15LQUAYrViTSNJAOK1XR29BQASgwDsy+gAkpPp2QC6uSDEUHJQAfGgOpgWaKBsmnCymAVMbNhsCMGYcAAer1QcRAYxoZAY6ksXVQhgAcnAnIYqjAHMF9Ax6I8YQApNiWQqCNhkCCGAA+hgAymwIVA4DDWqEqs9MOooiAjkpkOoANZvGzBZ5nZQ0WRke4gP7igBmNDggmUBRQSkwAE8cHACrIviK2UokH8aBBxYIkJ5BPpRXdUAAGbLHFXS2Xyt4-NUa9AARwYSBedACNFIIDtzRuVoeTxeBUwbBwP3+gLiByUEGYofdIBTTDTQc5Nl56Gs6gFsiFIrF4QljrlCvQSpAqvVmu1sl1LQNRorJrNFrIVtt9qrzoLrsbnu9vsCOkDwaOQA)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91},
      {"a": "E", "b": 81},
      {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19},
      {"a": "H", "b": 87},
      {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "title": {
        "orient": "bottom",
        "text": [
          "Figure 1: New Chart",
          "Author: Joe Blogs | Source: DataCentral"
        ]
      },
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
        "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "title": {"orient": "top", "text": [], "subtitle": "subtitle"},
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
        "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and code. 

If I also wish to add a title and subtitle above the bar chart at the same time what should my code look like. For example, add ....  

"title" {
"text": "Passenger Traffic",
"subtitle": "Port of Seattle"
}

Comment: I don't think there is any option to add text above and below in a single view.

Comment: Thanks. If its not possible to have both at same time in a single view ...... is it possible to add the 2 rows of text below the chart via " "vconcat" instead.

Comment: yes in `vconcat` it can be added, I have updated the answer. Since you are new, it would be better that you first try the examples from docs then you ask the questions.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. Have been working through numerous examples for past several days.